# How can I append an incremental count to every line of a text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a large document with over 500000 lines like this

```
car
milk
dog
```

And I want to count every line and add the number in the end of line and the final document to look like this

```
car1
milk1
dog1
car2    
milk2
dog2
car3
milk3
dog3
```

or like this. It dooesn't matter the order of the output lines

```
car1
car2
car3
milk1
milk2
milk3
dog1
dog2
dog3
```

And I created a script for this

```
for (( i=0; i<=999; i++))
do
awk '{ print $1 '$i' }' inputfile >> outputfile
done
```

But the script it works just with small files and I don't know why.

Comment: "And I want to add in the end of every line a number" . This number, can you clarify what this number is meant to do , or, how you decide what line gets what number, it would help figure out what answer to give you.

Comment: Like in the example. I want to count every line from 1 to 999.

Comment: Your script only has one variable (`i`) but your examples show each distinct string being incremented separately. Which do you want?

Comment: `awk '{print $0""++a[$0]}' <file` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the whole file *n* times with a numerical suffix from 1 to *n* added at each repetition:

```
n=999
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$n" ]; do
  sed "s/\$/$i/" <inputfile
  i=$((i+1))
done >outputfile
```

To repeat each line *n* times with a numerical suffix from 1 to *n*:

```
awk -v n=999 '{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $0 i}' <inputfile >outputfile
```